# How to send information to Android application from website

Tags: android, mobile-website

I have to write the pair of software: an website and an Android application.

The thing is: client installs the application (with all the permissions it needs). It can work in background on start-up (but don't have if it's not necessary).

Then, client visit the website. When he make certain action (click on link to some file), my application (installed previously) have to perform some operation (download the file and make something with it).

In other words, **I want to send some information from my website to my application on Android.**

**How to achieve it in Android?**

The problem is, **I don't want any additional confirmation dialogs or actions from client to be required** (like e.g. download file to disk, find it, run the program on it, click "accept" etc. etc.).

Of course, the installation of application will be typical, with all the confirmations.

So far I was thinking about such scenario:
*Application is running in background and checks if client has performed an action on my website (taking the result of http request from www.../somethingNew?user=user as an information about user actions). If so, application download the content (e.g. www.../?user=user will return the content clicked by user).*

The main disadvantage: it requires that application asks website **frequently**.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is pushnotifications. Please read about push notifications in android. If any changes in your website it will alert the user and then u can perform some operations based on it.

Comment: As far as I know "On Android devices, when a device receives a push notification, your application's icon and a message appear in the status bar. Then user has to click on it." - so it won't be automatic (another user action is required). Am I wrong?

Comment: i think on notify u can perform some other operations as well instead of showing on a notification bar. Because when you press download app on google play on the play website from a computer then it will be automatically downloaded on your phone. That is how u want it to work, am i right?

Comment: Yes you're wrong. When the server sends a push notification, your app receives a Broadcast in a registered BroadcastReceiver. From that BroadcastReceiver you can do anything you want, download a file, show a notification, start a background sync service, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the push notification requires the user to have Google Play Services enabled. And I don't want to be limited by it.